# Why is my top linear gradient working but not bottom?

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

I have a background image, and I want the linear gradient to be on both the top and bottom. I thought the CSS I had was supposed to work, but I can only get the top gradient to work. There is a div below the features div, and I'm wondering if that is messing something up? I am bashing my head right now :D

```
  .features{
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fff, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff);
  background-image: url('assets/Background_Features.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }

<div class="container-fluid p-x-0 features text-xs-center">

</div>
<div class="container-fluid p-x-0 p-b-3 m-t-3 pricing text-xs-center">

</div>
```

Link: http://jakeford.io/pwi-test/home.html

Comment: Well, the last div in your question does not have the `features` class so that might be the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine multiple gradient stops with multiple backgrounds definition passed with coma delimiter rather than overwriting one background-image rule with another. Here is a codepen for your use case:

http://codepen.io/MakiBM/pen/NRaWrr

```
.bg {
  ...
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, white, transparent 40%, transparent 60%, white),
    url('https://a2ua.com/mountains/mountains-007.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And some resources about both both technics:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, you were right Bartek, I was giving the gradient to the background of the div, instead of the actual background-image. Too many background rules.

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.000000001), rgba(255, 255, 255, .99)),
                url('assets/Background_Features.jpg');
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28248%5C%2C80%5C%2C50%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28241%5C%2C111%5C%2C92%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28246%5C%2C41%5C%2C12%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2051%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28240%5C%2C47%5C%2C23%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2071%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28231%5C%2C56%5C%2C39%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B') to generate gradient colors in CSS, try first the use without any webkit.